# Pass file from client application to aspcore mvc application and have file ready to upload c# asp.netcore mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Scenario:
I have a calling client application which will, in the end generate a .pdf that needs to be emailed out. I have created a aspcore mvc application that acts as an email composer. One of the actions takes the email parameters e.g. To, Cc.. etc and pre-populates part or all of the email form for them to review and press send.

Issue:
I'm struggling to pass across a file path to be used in the form as attachment. I also don't think that this is the safest way to do it as it could lead to multiple security vulnerabilities.

My attachments prop from my email class:

```
public List<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }
```

If the calling app hasn't passed an attachment file path across, the user can use the file input box to select one manually. This works fine. However if a file path is sent across, I can't get this to pre-populate the file input box, like I do with the rest of the form.

```
            if (attachment != null)
        {
            var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(attachment);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            var result = new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
            IFormFile file = new FormFile(result.FileStream, 0, result.FileStream.Length, "filename", "filename.pdf")
            {
                Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                ContentType = "application/pdf",
            };

            attachmentList.Add(file);
        }
```

I then add it to my model to be passed to the view to pre-populate.

Can you suggest a working way to achieve what I need? and or suggest different ways to achieve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I can't get this to pre-populate the file input box"

...you mean in a browser? No, you can't do that, for security reasons. The browser does not have the ability to specify a file on the user's device without user interaction. This is to prevent malicious websites being able to surreptitiously read otherwise-private data from the filesystems of devices. (And to be honest it's impractical anyway - different operating systems have different filesystem structures, and of course not all files exist on all devices, so specifying a path that would always work is basically impossible.)

But anyway I'm not sure your requirement makes much sense either - from what I can tell you've already generated the PDF and sent it to the MVC application. So the MVC application should just store the file on the server, and then associate it with the form when it's finalised and submitted by the user. Even if it was possible, there would be no value in uploading it a second time.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand your comments about security and the users device... I wanted to avoid having to store the file passed from the calling application, and just wanted to have it in memory until the email is sent, then dispose.

Comment: Well if it's not very big you could store it in the session as a byte array, so it stays in the server's memory rather than in persistent storage. But even if you store it on a disk or in a database, you can still remove it after the email is sent (or clear it out using a background job if the user never completes submission of the form).

Comment: I did consider storing it in session, but as the file could sometimes be a few MB, that wasn't going to work. I may have to explore the idea of just saving it on disk and removing it at the end of the submission. I think it would mean that the initial call would have to be a post to a different action so that the file would upload and then redirect to the form and populate the message and have a reference of the file for when it's ready to send. Does that sound right? Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: Yep that would make sense. Or you could just have the entire form in the client application and let the user complete it all there, and just send the data to an API endpoint on the server to submit and send the email in one hit.

Comment: The email app will end up being used by several client applications so it's prob not ideal to have the form in each one.

Comment: Perhaps not then. Depends on your preferred architecture. Some would say just build an API endpoint and let each client have a way to interact with it which suits that client app. But your idea is valid too if they're basically all going to make use of it in the same way.